# Struts tags not working

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have the following line in my jsp file

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<ww:property value="publicKey"/>"></div>
```

but the HTML output of that is exactly the same, the tag doesn´t get parsed. The corresponding action has the publicKey attribute defined along with its getters and setters. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the tag lib Encoding

```
<%@ taglib prefix="ww" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

And Check whether you have struts2-core.jar

Comment: This fixed it. I was missing the taglib. Thanks!!